Is there any way to obtain a list of all huddles with date and duration in slack?
Is there any way to get a list of all huddles is Slack with date and duration.
I tried using the search, but this was hit or miss and not really useful. I also tried searching for the phrase "A huddle has happened" but this returned zero results. I have daily huddles.
I looked at some Reddit posts on customizing navigation. I see no such options under the "three dot" menu.
Is there any way at all to pull a list of huddles from Slack?
I have been just paging through slack channels and typing the huddle date and duration into Excel. This is probably the only reliable method.
